# IdentityServer3 using reference tokens

Tags: c#, identityserver3

I have a project that I was setting up using reference tokens and it was working. But now I am getting an error:

> Error returned from introspection endpoint: Not Found

Which is odd, because I don't think I have changed anything.
I can't find any documentation to help with this issue :(
I have set up my application like this:

```
public static class Config
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Configures identity server
    /// </summary>
    public static void ConfigureIdentityServer(this IAppBuilder app, CormarConfig config)
    {
        // Create our options
        var identityServerOptions = new IdentityServerOptions
        {
            SiteName = "API",
            SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),
            IssuerUri = "https://api-test.azurewebsites.net",

            LoggingOptions = new LoggingOptions
            {
                EnableHttpLogging = true,
                EnableWebApiDiagnostics = true,
                EnableKatanaLogging = true,
                WebApiDiagnosticsIsVerbose = true
            },

            Factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory().Configure(config),

            Endpoints = new EndpointOptions()
            {
                EnableAccessTokenValidationEndpoint = false
            },

            // Disable when live
            EnableWelcomePage = true
        };

        // Setup our auth path
        app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp => { idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(identityServerOptions); });
    }


    /// <summary>
    ///     Configures the identity server to use token authentication
    /// </summary>
    public static void ConfigureIdentityServerTokenAuthentication(this IAppBuilder app, HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://api-test.azurewebsites.net/identity",
            DelayLoadMetadata = true,
            //ValidationMode = ValidationMode.Both,
            RequiredScopes = new[] {"api"},

            ClientId = "api",
            ClientSecret = "8at?7nAtaB!E"
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Configures Autofac DI/IoC
    /// </summary>
    public static IContainer ConfigureAutofac(this IAppBuilder app, HttpConfiguration config, Assembly assembly)
    {
        // Create our container
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // You can register controllers all at once using assembly scanning...
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(assembly);

        // Register our module            
        builder.RegisterModule(new CormarModule(app));

        // Filters
        builder.RegisterType<LogExceptionFilterAttribute>().AsWebApiExceptionFilterFor<IHttpController>();
        builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);

        // Build
        var container = builder.Build();

        // Lets Web API know it should locate services using the AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        // Return our container
        return container;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Loads the certificate
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
    {
        var certPath = $"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}App_Data\\idsrv3test.pfx";
        var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        var certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "asdf", false);
        certStore.Close();

        // If we are on azure, get the actual self signed certificate, otherwise return the test one
        return certCollection.Count > 0 ? certCollection[0] : new X509Certificate2(certPath, "idsrv3test");
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Configure the identity service factory with custom services
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static IdentityServerServiceFactory Configure(this IdentityServerServiceFactory factory, CormarConfig config)
    {
        var serviceOptions = new EntityFrameworkServiceOptions {ConnectionString = config.SqlConnectionString};
        factory.RegisterOperationalServices(serviceOptions);
        factory.RegisterConfigurationServices(serviceOptions);
        factory.CorsPolicyService = new Registration<ICorsPolicyService>(new DefaultCorsPolicyService {AllowAll = true}); // Allow all domains to access authentication

        factory.Register(new Registration<DbContext>(dr => dr.ResolveFromAutofacOwinLifetimeScope<DbContext>()));
        factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(dr => dr.ResolveFromAutofacOwinLifetimeScope<IUserService>());
        factory.ClientStore = new Registration<IClientStore>(dr => dr.ResolveFromAutofacOwinLifetimeScope<IClientStore>());
        factory.ScopeStore = new Registration<IScopeStore>(dr => dr.ResolveFromAutofacOwinLifetimeScope<IScopeStore>());

        return factory;
    }
}
```

These are invoked from the **Startup.cs** like so:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Cors must be first, or it will not work
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");

        // Get our configuration
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var container = app.ConfigureAutofac(config, assembly);
        var scope = config.DependencyResolver.GetRootLifetimeScope();
        ConfigureWebApi(config);

        // Create our logger and assign it to 
        ConfigureLogger(scope.Resolve<CormarConfig>());

        // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST. This also adds
        // Autofac-injected middleware registered with the container.
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        app.ConfigureIdentityServer(scope.Resolve<CormarConfig>());
        app.ConfigureIdentityServerTokenAuthentication(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

When I try to get my access token from **/connect/token**, it works. I get my token, but if I then try to access any controller, I always get the 401 access denied and my logs show the error above plus:

> invalid bearer token received

Does anyone know if I am missing a step?

I have added the [AccessTokenValidation](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation/blob/master/source/AccessTokenValidation/Plumbing/IntrospectionEndpointTokenProvider.cs) nuget to my project, but don't know what else I am supposed to do with it (if anything).
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the error received is not pertinent to the cause.
The cause in this case was do to the **IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions.Authority** being incorrect. It has to be the actual path to the identity server.
Changing it to the correct path fixed my issue and all started working.